# This page requires AC_RunActiveContent_QueryString.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have updated my wordpress site to Wordpress 4.6.1 version, after that my site is showing following pop up message.

"This page requires AC_RunActiveContent_QueryString.js."

Can somebody let me know how can I fix this?

Comment: You were embedding content using AC_RunActiveContent_QueryString.js?

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the same problem and found your post - so in case the problem isn't fixed?

At the site I looked at there was a link set up to a non-existent JavaScript file at easyfundraising.org.uk in one of the side column text widgets:

```
<script src="http://www.easyfundraising.org.uk/js/AC_RunActiveContent_QueryString.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

... and below this (in a another widget) some JavaScript

```
<!-- START BANNER -->
<script language="javascript">AC_FL_RunContent_QueryString = 0;</script>
<script src="http://www.easyfundraising.org.uk/js/AC_RunActiveContent_QueryString.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
 if (AC_FL_RunContent_QueryString == 0) {
  alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent_QueryString.js.");
 } else {
```

Deleting both Text widgets removed the popup.